# Sodaq Moja — Accessing SW2/SW3 user switches

Tags: documentation

I have a Sodaq Moja, from supporting the project on Kickstarter, and I didn't have much time until now to play with it. Unfortunately, the online documentation for the Moja has disappeared, and only the docs for the new version, the Mbili, is accessible. And nowhere can I see where to access the user switches. Which, to boot, have been reordered in the Mbili, can cut down from 3 to 2.

Would anyone have an idea?

Cheers,

Comment: It took me about 15 seconds to get all the information you could ever want about the Moja, including the schematic.  You didn't try very hard.  Here's the schematic: https://github.com/SodaqMoja/SodaqMojaBoard and there is tons more stuff in other repositories: https://github.com/SodaqMoja

Comment: I went through the github repository but didn't find any code related to sw2/sw3. Did you? The 15 seconds you spent were obviously lazy and useless...

Comment: I have to ask: what "user switches" are you thinking you are trying to use?  The Moja has no user switches as you can tell by looking at your board and cross-referencing what you see there with what is on the schematic I pointed to.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the schematics](https://github.com/SodaqMoja/SodaqMojaBoard) and pictures of the Moja, the Sodaq Moja has no "User Switches".

There are 2 buttons and 1 switch.  The switch is a general power on-off switch.  One button (SW2) is the master reset button for the ATMega328P.  The other button, SW3, is the reset for the X-Bee daughter board.

None of those can be used programmatically.